# Issues with division: casting an int return type to float, returning 0

Tags: c, casting, floating-point, division

***This is part of an assignment, the assignment is unrelated to the casting, its something I'm trying to do on my own.***

I'm having issues with casting an int return type to a float in a division function. It keeps returning 0, despite having the correct value in the division function. I have read a bunch of different posts regarding int division considerations and rounding down, and I have tried implementing a variety of different solutions to no avail.

I have a workable solution to just print from within the function, but I'm trying to stay consistent throughout my program and deal with the returned value.

**Edit (clarity):** *The divide function has a return type int because I'm trying to keep its return type consistent with a bunch of other calculator functions that have return type int (in a dispatch table). I'm trying to see if its possible to return a fractional floating point, via casting, from a function with an int return type.*

Here is the relevant truncated code to reproduce the problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXARGS 15
#define min(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (a) : (b))

struct argList {
  int count;
  char *args[MAXARGS];
} argList;

//Division function
int divide(int c, struct argList l){
  float a = (strtol(l.args[0], NULL, 0));
  float b = (strtol(l.args[1], NULL, 0));
  printf("\nIn Func = %f\n", a/b);
  return (float)(a/b);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  int argCount = min(argc-1, MAXARGS); 

  int i = 0;
  for (i = 0, argv++; i<argCount; i++) {
    argList.args[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]+1));
    strncpy(argList.args[i], argv[i], strlen(argv[i])+1);
  }
  argList.count = i;


  printf("Out of Func = %f\n", (float)divide(argList.count, argList));
  
  return 0;
}
```

Sample outputs:

```
./main 2 5

In Func = 0.400000
Out of Func = 0.000000


./main 10 5

In Func = 2.000000
Out of Func = 2.000000
```

The fact that the second input works leads me to believe its still a problem with the integer division/rounding that is frequently mentioned. But I figured with the casting of the function call and return type that it would avoid that issue.

Let me know if anyone has any ideas to resolve this issue.

**EDIT: Attempted solutions:**

Casting one operand, casting both operands, creating a separate variable, multiplying by 100.0f, using `strtof` and `strtod` instead of casting to an `strol`.

Comment: You should cast the operands (one is enough), not the result (which is already zero)

Comment: That doesn't change the output. I've tried casting one, both, doing the division outside the return and returning a separate variable, etc. 

All the same result.

Comment: Because your `divide` is returning `int` as well for some reason.

Comment: Right, I explained it in the middle of the original post. Im working with a function dispatch table of a bunch of different functions, they're all of return type int, so the goal is to keep divide as a return type int but cast the resulting value to a float type.

Comment: Then how do you expect an `int` function to return a fractional number? Cast will cast the already truncated result, which is not what you seem to expect.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that was expressed, but thats what Im trying to figure out. How to resolve the truncation problem.

Comment: Your requirements are contradictory. You can't both have a function with `int` return type and have it return fractional `float`. Since we don't see the full picture, it will be hard to suggest the proper solution. But looks like the design should be revisited.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I thought the post was clear in the fact that I had a function with an int return type and was attempting to cast the return into a fractional float. I did not know it was impossible, I thought that was the point of being able to cast the return to different types. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cast a float to int and then to a float. you will probably never get the original float.

What you need is to take what is present in the memory and consider it as an int. To do this kind of manipulation you use an union:

For example You add:

```
typedef union {
  float f;
  int   i;
} IF_t;
```

In divide function you replace the print and the return by:

```
IF_t r;
r.f = a/b;
printf("\nIn Func = %f\n", r.f);
return r.i;
```

and you replace the printf in the main by:

```
res.i = divide(argList.count, argList);
printf("Out of Func = %f\n", res.f);
```

of course you declare `IF_t res;` in the main.

Answer (score 1):

At least these problem:

Code is finding the length of some of the argument.  This error later leads to *undefined behavior* (UB) in later code as insufficient memory is allocated.

```
// argList.args[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]+1));
argList.args[i] = malloc(strlen(argv[i]) + 1);
```

Why convert to an integer, then `float`?  Go right to a `float`.

```
// float a = (strtol(l.args[0], NULL, 0));
float a = strtod(l.args[0], NULL);
// or better
float a = strtof(l.args[0], NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you, the first portion is part of some other code I'm working on, I tried to just include what was relevant to get the return type problem to be repeatable.

I tried both the solutions in the second part and the return is the same.